# How to implement SnapMode for Grid in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qt4, qml

I need to use a grid(not gridview) and i need to achieve GridView.SnapToRow for the same.

Below is my code:

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
width: 1368
height: 768

Text{
    id:parentTxt
    anchors.top: parentTxt0.bottom
}
Timer{running: true;repeat: false;interval:200;onTriggered: {calc()}}
function calc(){
    var totalItems=testGrid.count+((testBtn.visible)?1:0)
    var dividedVal=totalItems/testGrid.columns
    var absVal=Math.floor(dividedVal)
    var diffVal=dividedVal-absVal;
    testGrid.rowCount=(diffVal>0)?(absVal+1):absVal
    parentTxt.text=testGrid.rowCount
}

Text{
    id:parentTxt0
    text:"Move up"
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: {
            calc()
            gridFlick.contentY+=137
        }
    }
}
Text{
    id:parentTxt02
    text:"Move down"
    anchors.left: parentTxt0.right
    anchors.leftMargin: 20
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: {
            calc()
            if(gridFlick.contentY!=0)gridFlick.contentY-=137
        }
    }
}
Text{
    id:parentTxt03
    text:"toggleVisiblitiy"
    anchors.left: parentTxt02.right
    anchors.leftMargin: 20
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: {
            testBtn.visible=!testBtn.visible;
            calc()
        }
    }
}
Rectangle {
    width: 770
    height: 274
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color:"#330000ff"
    clip:true;

    Flickable{

        id:gridFlick
        interactive: true;
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        contentWidth: testGrid.width; contentHeight: 137*testGrid.rowCount
        flickableDirection:Flickable.VerticalFlick
        boundsBehavior:Flickable.StopAtBounds
        Grid{
            id:testGrid
            property int count:15
            property int rowCount: 0
            columns: 5;
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            Rectangle{
                id:testBtn
                color:"transparent"
                height:137
                width: 154
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent;
                    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                    text: "back"
                }
                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        parentTxt.text="back"
                    }
                }
            }
            Repeater{
                model:testGrid.count;
                delegate:Rectangle{
                    color:"transparent"
                    height:137
                    width: 154
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent;
                        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                        text:  index
                    }

                    MouseArea{
                        anchors.fill: parent;
                        onClicked: {
                            parentTxt.text=index
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Can any one provide some idea to this?

Answer (score 0):

i did a work around using the following code.This seems to work now

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
width: 1368
height: 768

Text{
    id:parentTxt
    anchors.top: parentTxt0.bottom
}
TextEdit{
    id:logTxt
    height:100;width:parent.width;
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    function log(txt){
        text=txt+"\n"
    }
}
Timer{running: true;repeat: false;interval:200;onTriggered: {calc()}}
function calc(){
    var totalItems=testGrid.count+((testBtn.visible)?1:0)
    var dividedVal=totalItems/testGrid.columns
    var absVal=Math.floor(dividedVal)
    var diffVal=dividedVal-absVal;
    testGrid.rowCount=(diffVal>0)?(absVal+1):absVal
    parentTxt.text=testGrid.rowCount
}

Text{
    id:parentTxt0
    text:"Move up"
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: {
            calc()
            gridFlick.contentY+=137
        }
    }
}
Text{
    id:parentTxt02
    text:"Move down"
    anchors.left: parentTxt0.right
    anchors.leftMargin: 20
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: {
            calc()
            if(gridFlick.contentY!=0)gridFlick.contentY-=137
        }
    }
}
Text{
    id:parentTxt03
    text:"toggleVisiblitiy"
    anchors.left: parentTxt02.right
    anchors.leftMargin: 20
    MouseArea{
        anchors.fill: parent;
        onClicked: {
            testBtn.visible=!testBtn.visible;
            calc()
        }
    }
}

Rectangle {
    width: 770
    height: 274
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color:"#330000ff"
    clip:true;
    Flickable{

        id:gridFlick
        interactive: true;
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        contentWidth: testGrid.width; contentHeight: 137*testGrid.rowCount
        flickableDirection:Flickable.VerticalFlick
        boundsBehavior:Flickable.StopAtBounds
        onFlickEnded:{
            logTxt.log("onFlickEnded")
        }

        onFlickStarted:{
            logTxt.log("onFlickStarted")
        }

        onMovementEnded:{
            logTxt.log("onMovementEnded")
            gridView.contentY=gridFlick.contentY
        }

        onMovementStarted:{
            logTxt.log("onMovementStarted")
        }

        Grid{
            id:testGrid
            property int count:15
            property int rowCount: 0
            columns: 5;
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            Rectangle{
                id:testBtn
                color:"transparent"
                height:137
                width: 154
                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent;
                    wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                    text: "back"
                }
                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent;
                    onClicked: {
                        parentTxt.text="back"
                    }
                }
            }
            Repeater{
                model:testGrid.count;
                delegate:Rectangle{
                    color:"transparent"
                    height:137
                    width: 154
                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent;
                        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                        text:  index
                    }

                    MouseArea{
                        anchors.fill: parent;
                        onClicked: {
                            parentTxt.text=index
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }



    GridView{
        id:gridView
        boundsBehavior:GridView.StopAtBounds
        snapMode:GridView.SnapToRow
        width: 770
        height: 274
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        cellHeight: 137;cellWidth:154;
        model:testGrid.count+1
        clip:true;
        onContentYChanged: {
            gridFlick.contentY=contentY
            logTxt.log(contentY)
        }

        onFlickEnded:{
            logTxt.log("gridView | onFlickEnded | "+gridView.contentY)
        }

        onFlickStarted:{
            logTxt.log("gridView | onFlickStarted | "+gridView.contentY)
        }

        onMovementEnded:{
            logTxt.log("gridView | onMovementEnded | "+gridView.contentY)
//            gridView.contentY=gridFlick.contentY
        }

        onMovementStarted:{
            logTxt.log("gridView | onMovementStarted | "+gridView.contentY)
        }

        delegate:Rectangle{
            color:"transparent"
            height:gridView.cellHeight
            width: gridView.cellWidth
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent;
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
                text:  index
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Can any one provide any other solution?

Comment: I need a solution without the use of a gridview